# I cannot understand the skipgrams() function in keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, keras, text-processing

I am trying to understand the `skipgrams()` function in keras by using the following code

```
from keras.preprocessing.text import *
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import skipgrams

text = "I love money" #My test sentence
tokenizer = Tokenizer()
tokenizer.fit_on_texts([text])
word2id = tokenizer.word_index
wids = [word2id[w] for w in text_to_word_sequence(text)]
pairs, labels = skipgrams(wids, len(word2id),window_size=1)

for i in range(len(pairs)): #Visualizing the result
    print("({:s} , {:s} ) -> {:d}".format(
          id2word[pairs[i][0]], 
          id2word[pairs[i][1]], 
          labels[i]))
```

For the sentence "I love money", I would expect the following `(context, word)` pairs with the window size=1 as defined in keras:

```
([i, money], love)
([love], i)
([love], money)
```

From what I understand in Keras' documentation, it will output the label of 1 if `(word, word in the same window)` , and the label of 0 if `(word, random word from the vocabulary)`.

Since I am using the windows size of 1, I would expect the label of 1 for the following pairs:

```
(love, i)
(love, money)
(i, love)
(money, love)
```

And the label of 0 for the following pairs

```
(i, money)
(money, i)
```

Yet, the code give me the result like this

```
(love , i ) -> 1
(love , money ) -> 1
(i , love ) -> 1
(money , love ) -> 1    
(i , i ) -> 0
(love , love ) -> 0
(love , i ) -> 0
(money , love ) -> 0
```

How can the pair `(love , i )` and `(money , love )` be labelled as both 0 and 1?
and also where is the `(i, money)` and `(money, i)` result?

Am I understanding things wrongly that the labels of 0 are all out of my expectation? But it seems I understand the label of 1 quite well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because your vocabulary is very small: it's the same `("love", "i", "money")` words. That's why "random word from the vocabulary" is always from the same sentence and moreover from the same context.

As an experiment, do this:

```
text = "I love money" #My test sentence
text2 = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, " \
        "sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua"
tokenizer = Tokenizer()
tokenizer.fit_on_texts([text, text2])
...
```

Basically, let the tokenizer know that there are more words in the text. You should see that the negative examples are now generated mostly from the second sentence, for example:

```
(i , sit ) -> 0
(love , i ) -> 1
(love , money ) -> 1
(love , ut ) -> 0
(love , sit ) -> 0
(money , consectetur ) -> 0
(money , love ) -> 1
(i , love ) -> 1
```

Comment: Thanks! I understand it now.

Comment: Side-question: what's the point of creating negative samples in the skiagram word pair generation process?